# The %run magic and programmatically fetching a notebook's path using Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Consider the following structure:

```
.
├── alpha
│   ├── data.yml
│   └── notebook1
└── beta
    └── notebook2
```

Where in `notebook1` I need to read the data available in `data.yml` which will be processed inside this very notebook. In addition, in `notebook2` I need to run ("import") `notebook1`.  To that end I use something like `%run ../alpha/noteboo1`.

I fail to keep a consistent reference to `data.yml`. How can I read `data.yml` consistently and independently of how the notebook is executed?

Here's what I tried so far:

### Using relative path

```py
with open("./data.yml", "r") as f:
    pass
```

This works when running `notebook1`, but it doesn't work when `notebook1` is ran from `notebook2`. In the latter case, it is trying to read the file `beta/data.yml` which doesn't exist.

### Programmatically fetch the path

Using something like `dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()` returns the location of `notebook1` when executed directly from `notebook1`. **BUT,** again when executed using the `%run` magic, it evaluates to the path of `notebook2`.

Answer (score 0):

your described issue occurs due to the nature of `%run`: [Link to databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#comparison-of-run-and-dbutilsnotebookrun)

Whenever you execute a notebook with %run, its contents are effectively copied into the current notebook execution context. Thus your path reference will fail as you have described.

*Approach 1:* Identify the root directory and programmatically add relative path

I've faced very similar issues in a current project, where we have configuration that needs to be loaded from various calling notebooks in differing locations. We've approaches this by identifying the root directory of our folder strcuture and then creating a relative path reference to the target directory like so:

using OS:

```py
import os

user_dir = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().userName().get()
path = os.getcwd().split('/')
pos = path.index(user_dir)

relative_path = "../" * (len(path)-pos-1) + "target_directory"
```

Using collections:

```py
import collections

full_path = (
    dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils()
    .notebook()
    .getContext()
    .notebookPath()
    .get()
)

user_dir = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().userName().get()

root_position = full_path.find(f"/{user_dir}/")
right_path = full_path[root_position:]
count_hierarchies = collections.Counter(right_path)["/"] - 1

relative_path = "../" * count_hierarchies + "target_directory"
```

Using os is limited somewhat as, when run from Workspace/ location it will return `'/databricks/driver'`. The collections approach works there too.

But I suppose, since you are loading a yaml file, you're running from within Repos/ with the setting Files in Repos enabled. So both ways should work fine.

*Approach 2:* Change the approach to executing the notebook:

Another way to remedy that would be to run the notebooks in a seperate spark context by leveraging the dbutils library: `dbutils.notebook.run(<path_to_notebook1>)`.

This has the downside that any variables created in that execution context are not available in calling spark session. Instead you would need to return the outputs to the calling notebook, by passing them through for example task variables or `dbutils.notebook.exit(return_variable)` - or you store them as a table and reimport in the calling notebook.

If that works within your setup, that's grand.
I ususally perfer using dbutils.notebook.run for parameterized executions of notebooks, that don't need to return much. so for importing a config it's not ideal.

Dbutils enables you to more easily pass parameters to the executed notebook / parameterize the notebook execution altogether. %run does allow that.

Comment: I'm afraid that the 1st approach won't work for me because the root will change depending on the user who runs the notebook(s). I think the 2nd approach is the better one, but unfortunately, it would require a lot of refactoring to notebooks.

Comment: What we could do to modify approach 1 a bit is to determine the user directory as root. I'm assuming that the different users will be running a 'personal' copy from within their respective user directories? (Hence root not being able to be hardcoded)

You could simply set it programmatically too:
`user_drive = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().userName().get()`

dbutils has got you covered ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree to *@Horst724* on identifying the root directory.

I have tried the below steps to resolve your issue:-

You need to store the `data.yml` file path from root filesystem.
That is

```
dbutils.fs.ls("file:/")
```

[image]

This is the root filesystem python search for.
In my case the **notebooks** and **config.yml** are under `Workspace`.

Similarly, add your path from root directory.

```
path = "/Workspace/Users/xxxx@xxxx.com"
file_path = "/alpha/config.yml"
with  open(path+file_path, "r") as f:
    print("read config.yml")
    pass
```

Output in notebook 1

[image]

Output in notebook 2.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there an issue with the approach when it's ran by another user? The path `/Workspace/Users/xxxx@xxxx.com` will change when someone else is running the notebook.

Comment: @Dror As @Horst724 mentioned you can get user as below
`user_drive = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().userName().get()`.
If other user runs this in his private space then the path will be
`path= f"/Workspace/Users/{user_drive}/<path_to_file.>"`.
If other user is runs notebook in shared space then
path will be `path=f"/Workspace/Shared/<path_to_file>"`